# Is it good practise to construct and house an automation framework inside the same directory of the application under test?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

Currently I'am constructing an automation framework but need clarification on whether its a good idea to house the automation framework within the same directory of the application under test?

Example: I have developed an automation framework using Selenium WebDriver and Java and the application I'm creating scripts to test is built upon HTML, CSS and JavaScript, is it a good idea to house both projects together or seperate the maven project in isolation from the system under test (Website)

Comment: Have answered it, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your common framework should be an different entity and should be used like any other maven dependency and that common framework should not contain the tests for your application under test.

Its recommended that you should have the common framework as a different project and you should upload it in your nexus and use it as a jar in the application under test project. It's like making another maven dependency which would solve your common configurations and utilities problems.

Biggest advantage of that would be: Lets say you are working on web application and you have made the common framework and the web application tests in the same project and in future, if your application starts supporting mobile web as well, then you would need to make all the configuration and setup again which you have already made in the previous project. So, in order to make your code more usable and scalable, the common framework should be complete different project and there should not be any tests written in it so that in near future, whenever you need to support any other platform with the automation, you just need to add the common framework jar in that project and you would be able to fetch all the methods and configurations easily.

Hope that helps and answers your question!!

Comment: @ameer Arora thank you so much for your detailed comment, how would I handle Page Objects (Using Page Object Modelling), lets say I create a framework which has specific Java classes representing pages of a website (Selectors, custom methods), would I be able to interact with the given pages if I was to import my framework into another as a JAR file?

Comment: Yes yes you would be able to use the framework seamlessly which you import it as a jar in your new project. I have also done it so i can vouch on that :)

Comment: And please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks @Sameer Arora :)

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: Thanks again @Sameer Arora one last question, sorry to be a pain, would I be able to store page objects inside of the project, which I import as a jar file?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get the question..

Comment: No worries @Sameer Arora, 

Lets say I have two projects
Project A: Contains custom methods, page objects and locators. 
Project B: Will use project A as a jar file, would I still be able to use the page objects and locators housed in Project A even though I have only added projected A into project B as a jar files?

Comment: Well ideally you shouldn’t have any locators in the common framework as the common framework will be shared by all the projects so those locators might not be of use in some other project. Common framework should contain the common methods and utilities which would be shared across all the projects and projects should have their own locators inside their project only.

Comment: Appreciate your help @Sameer Arora